# KeyError(key) Error in Pytest cx_Oracle connection error

Tags: python, oracle, pytest

Hey I tried to connect oracle db in pytest It shows following  error
raise KeyError(key)  KeyError: 'db'

code

```
@pytest.fixture
def session(): 
    config_file="dataflow.ini"
    config_path = "%s/%s" % (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])),config_file)
    config_ini = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config_ini.read(config_path)
    print("db" in config_ini)
    # create oracle connection
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(config_ini['db']['host'], config_ini['db']['port'], 
    config_ini['db']['sid'])
    dbs = cx_Oracle.Connection(config_ini['db']['user'], config_ini['db']['passwd'],dsn_tns)
    db_session = dbs.cursor()
    # db_session = connection.cursor()
    yield db_session
    connection.close()
```

dataflow.ini

```
[db]
sid=****
user=***
passwd=*****
host=****
port=****
[encryption]
key=********
```

Traceback error

self = <configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x7f01c9b93198>, key = 'db'

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key != self.default_section and not self.has_section(key):
```

> ```
>       raise KeyError(key)
> ```

E           KeyError: 'db'

/usr/lib64/python3.6/configparser.py:959: KeyError
-------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup --------------------------------------------------
False
================================================= short test summary info =================================================
ERROR scripts/pytest_test_vai.py::test_get - KeyError: 'db'
==================================================== 1 error in 1.13s =====================================================

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong traceback error updated

Comment: Is that the full traceback error?  Also, try adding a ```print("db" in config_ini)``` after the ```config.read(config_path)```.  and update your post to show what it prints out

Comment: @ewong print statement not working

Comment: Debug it: remove code that may not be relevant.  Try simply printing values like `config_ini['db']['user']` instead of invoking cx_Oracle.